Of or from when we talk about materials
which way is correct?

A handbag of crocodile leather
A handbag from crocodile leather

Or both?

As you have specified the phrase, from is not natural, only of. As a preposition, from does not usually have the meaning of "of material".
But as a complement of the adjective made (or the verb make) from can have that meaning.
So if you said a handbag made of/from crocodile leather, either would be possible.


A handbag [made] of crocodile leather

This is grammatically correct without the verb "made", but not natural. It is better with "made".

A handbag [made] from crocodile leather

This is only OK if you add the word "made".
The normal way of saying it is

A crocodile leather handbag.

Crocodile leather is not a common material, so I have substituted canvas in this NGram Graph, which shows that "bag of canvas" is extremely uncommon compared to "canvas bag".
You might, though, say

This bag is made of/from crocodile leather.


I. Explanation of "Made of" vs. "Made from".
For understanding the concept better, I have added the verb "made".

Question: "Which is correct?".
A handbag made of crocodile leather.
A handbag made from crocodile leather.

Answer: "A handbag made from crocodile leather" is better..
General Rule:.

Made of: Used when the material’s physical form does not change during the making process.
Examples:
"She wore a beautiful necklace made of silver.
This chair is made of ivory..
Made from: Used when the material’s physical form does change during the making process.
Examples:
"Yoghurt is made from milk.".
"Paper is made from trees."

II. Additional prepositions with made:  made out of, made with..
Further clarification is given for other prepositions with "made".

Reference Cambridge dictionary.
Made from, made of, made out of, made with.
.
Made out of.
We usually use made out of when we talk about something that has been changed or transformed from one thing into another:
In the 1970s, it was popular to have candle-holders made out of wine bottles.
They were living in tents made out of old plastic sheets.
.
Made with.
We use made with most often to talk about the ingredients of food and drink:
This dish is made with chicken, red peppers and herbs.
Is sushi always made with raw fish or do the Japanese use cooked fish too?.

made from, made of, made out of, made with

Tons of thanks!
